# Publishing XY Event Layer with ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.4

How can I publish an XY event layer and have changes which are made to the table made to the XY  event layer published service as well?  I've made changes to the table, but they were not reflected in the published service. What is the solution so that I am able to see any changes made to the table, that they will be made to the XY event layer as well?

I am able to view the data via XY Event layer, which I initially thought was an in-memory layer, but it is, however,  an instance of the view/or data set that I am using.  The ideal scenario would be:

1. Make event layer of XY from SDE table
2. Publish service definition
3. All changes will be reflected in published event layer.

I am using ArcGIS Server 10.4.1

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that by default, this should work the way you intend as long as ArcGIS Server has access to the same SDE table the XY layer is based on. In the ArcGIS Server Manager, check under Site > GIS Server > Data Store and confirm that your SDE database is listed under Registered Databases, and if not, register it. I'm not sure this is your problem though, if the server can't access the data source, the layer wouldn't show up at all in your service (rather than just not updating when the table changes).

Comment: The data is showing up; the updates to the table are not reflected in the XY event layer.

Comment: Is the SDE table accessible to the server? When you publish a layer and the layer's source data is inaccessible to the server, I think the default behavior is that the act of publishing copies the data to the server so it can be displayed, but the link to the source data is broken. That may explain why the data shows up but doesn't update. Try publishing from ArcGIS Desktop if you aren't already, do the "Analyze" step and read all the warning messages.

Comment: I have created the service definition with the table and the event layer, changes are still not reflected in the event layer OR the table on the server.